# How can one see how much total reads and writes (in bytes) a given file has received cumulatively since Windows started?

Tags: window, io, disk-activity, disk-monitoring

I started Microsoft Windows a few hours ago. I would like to see how much total reads and writes (in bytes) a given file has received cumulatively since Windows started. Windows Results Monitor doesn't have this information: it only displays the current IO speed, as the screenshot below illustrates. How can one see how much total reads and writes (in bytes) a given file has received cumulatively since Windows started?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a third party tool, such as Nirsoft's [FileActivityWatch](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_activity_watch.html), to capture reads, writes and ancillary data, shown below.

[image: File Activity Watch]